# How do I create random numbers that are nonrepeating using applescript

Tags: applescript

Trying to figure out how to create non-repeating numbers using applescript.  If I want random numbers only 1 or 2, I would want my result to be [1, 2] or [2, 1] and never [1, 1] or [2, 1].

So I just basically need to figure out a way I can make sure the numbers are non-repeating, everything else I know how to do.  If there is a unix command I can run in applescript, let me know.

Comment: if you mean: `never [1,1] or [2,2]` you have only two choices: `[1,2]` or `[2,1]`. that's what you want?

Comment: If I do
set A to random number from 1 to 2
set B to random number from 1 to 2
If A = B then
set B not equal to A but set as a random number from 1 to 2

Comment: After you have a random A, automatically fill the remaining choice as B.  Or more likely, have a random value that is 0 or 1, and depending on which you output [1,2] or [2,1]

Comment: @ChrisStratton im trying to get it to work for values ranging from 1-2 first, but the end result is for 1-100.  So
A - 10
B - 50
and not
A - 10
B - 10

Comment: In that case, provided you have an infinite supply of random numbers, filtering out illegal results and replacing them with another try (as many times as necessary to get a legal result) may be simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

The next applescript will generate non-repeating random-number pairs - from the range 1..100

```
set maxValue to 100
set thePairs to {}
repeat until (count thePairs) = 2
   set randomNumber to (random number from 1 to maxValue)
   if thePairs does not contain {randomNumber} then set end of thePairs to randomNumber
end repeat
thePairs
```

*I hope than you will not modify the question again to something other.*

Comment: that worked:).  So how can i get it to work with what I have already
repeat
 set p to (random number from 1 to 100)
 set o to random number from 1 to 100)
 set po to [p, o]
 set poString to "{" & ((p) as text) & ", " & ((o) as text) & "}"
 display dialog "Numbers are:
 " & poString
end repeat

Comment: This is my second CORRECT answer to you question. You not accepted any. So, sorry - i'm not your personal developer. Try www.elance.com. Bye.

Comment: how would i incorporate what you provide to what I have already? thats the part i don't understand

Comment: Can someone please help me with this? I can't seem to get it.  See my image.